# Postgrex expected a boolean, got "1"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to pass a boolean value to hidden_input. But Postgrex doesn't seem to understand what I"m trying to pass in.

#### Here is my error:

```
Postgrex expected a boolean, got "1". Please make sure the value you are passing matches the definition in your table or in your query or convert the value accordingly.
```

#### FORM:

```
<%= inputs_for f, :users_leagues, fn ff -> %>
  <%= hidden_input ff, :commissioner, value: 1 %>
  <%= hidden_input ff, :user_id, value: assigns.current_user.id %>
  <%= hidden_input ff, :league_id, value: 1 %>
<% end %>
```

It also doesn't work if a just pass in `true` I'll get this error: `Postgrex expected a boolean, got "value"`

How do I pass a boolean value to a hidden field?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: How's that @Dogbert?

Comment: @Dogbert I figured it out. I had :string as the type in my schema. It should have been boolean... Silly mistake

Comment: You should post that as an answer. Might help someone searching for this error message!

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots, post plain text instead, as clearly stated in ToS. Thanks.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yea you're right. Dogbert asked for the backtrace and out of trying to meet his request I thought that it would be the easiest way to show him. Formatting that mess would have been hard.

Comment: @mudasobwa If you down voted this because of the screenshot I edited it. Would you consider removing the down vote if that was the reason? If you have other reasons that is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong:

I had my users_leagues schema set up like this:

```
schema "users_leagues" do
  field :commissioner, :string
end
```

It should be setup like this:

```
schema "users_leagues" do
  field :commissioner, :boolean
end
```

That matches the database records.